# Sorting a list by function result in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am trying to order a list using `sortBy` and `compare`, but I am having issues coming up with the compare expression. I need it to sort the list based on the average given back by the filmRating function.

```
formattedByYear :: Int -> String
formattedByYear year = concatMap formatString $ sortBy (compare filmRating) $ filmsByYear year

filmRating :: Film -> Float
filmRating (Film _ _ _ ratings)
      | ratings == [] = 0.0
      | otherwise = average (map snd ratings)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function you want is `Data.Ord.comparing`.

```
Prelude> :t Data.Ord.comparing
Data.Ord.comparing :: Ord a => (b -> a) -> b -> b -> Ordering
```

Comment: formattedByYear year = concatMap formatString $ sortBy (comparing filmRating) $ filmsByYear year gives me the same result.

Comment: It would be helpful to know what that result is.

Comment: Director: "Ridely Scott" 
Film Name: "Test" 
Year: 2012 
Rating: 1.50


Director: "Test1" 
Film Name: "Test1" 
Year: 2012 
Rating: 4.50

It should be ordered by rating.

Comment: It is. But ascending, of course. If you want higher ratings first, `sortBy (flip $ comparing filmRating)`.